# How to make Fingerprint reader of Dell latitude e6510 work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, dell

I want to make the fingerprint reader work.
Can you please help.
I seems like the system detects the fingerprint sensor

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5801 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:8187 Dell Computer Corp. DW375 Bluetooth Module
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ca:1814 Ricoh Co., Ltd HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have tired installing fprint using [this documentation](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint) and 
fingerprint gui using [this documentation](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui).

If i try to enrol it gives the following error:

```
$ fprintd-enroll
list_devices failed: No devices available
```

I have also attached the picture. That's how the software behaves after I open it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Have you tried anything yet?  Installing drivers?  Checking for support/compatibility?

Comment: You should make your question more clear and understanding, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Comment: No, I just installed fprint and finger print GUI . I couldn't find drivers for Linux

Answer (score 3):

The device is not supported on linux. Below is link to the bug on launchpad.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/602071?comments=all

Comment: Really. Is that it?  Not supported...live with it... Really makes me sometimes want to get back to windows world.

Comment: in that case the culprit here is the Broadcom company that for years do not want make devices compatible with Linux.